# Upgrading VS2005 solution to VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to upgrade my solution which is in VS2005 to VS2012. I have two projects inside this solution. One is a project which had the .csproj file in it, so was able to convert it successfully. But the second thing is a website (the main website) and which doesn't has any .csproj file in it and so I am not able to convert that into VS2012 and its failing to load that and the error says "Project file and Web cannot be found."

For a website, do we have to load different kind of file instead of .csproj file?

Any suggestions/comments?

Thanks!